# Can I use the cooling for my Pentium 4 with my new i5 CPU?

Tags: intel-core-i5, intel-pentium, cpu-cooler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use LGA775 heatsink on LGA1156 CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/126632/can-i-use-lga775-heatsink-on-lga1156-cpu)

I recently bought a new i5 2500k CPU, but with my current setup I run the risk of cooling issues. I have an improved heatsink and fan I purchased for my old Pentium 4 rig, and was wondering if I can use this cooling system with the new i5 CPU. The attachment seems to align correctly, and it'll fit nicely on the motherboard. I'm curious as to whether it'll have sufficient contact area and if it will conduct the heat correctly, though.

Comment: Even though the attachments line up correctly, there is no way to tell by the question. Typically motherboard model and heatsink model are needed to intelligently answer the question. I have a http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835103057 on my 2500k and have it safely clocked to 4.3GHz.

Comment: Why are you concerned about cooling on the i5 2500K?  You can probably run that thing with a significant overclock even on the stock Intel cooler...

Comment: The motherboard is an ASUS P8Z68-V PRO Z68 S-1155 ATX, and from what I can tell the heatsink model is an arctic-cooling Freezer Pro 7 - I don't have the packaging for the heatsink any more, so I don't really know.

Answer (score 3):

The LGA 1366, 1156, and 775 all have different hole layouts.  So unless you got a bracket to fit the appropriate LGA, I wouldn't bother.

A well placed stock cooler will beat the pants off a misplaced Freezer Pro 1000000000.

Comment: You can if your name is MacGyver...http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088559/

Comment: @Moab: Touche, well noted.