# Use LGA775 cooler for LGA1155

Tags: cpu-cooler, lga775

The question is somehow similar to [Can I use LGA775 heatsink on LGA1156 CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/126632/can-i-use-lga775-heatsink-on-lga1156-cpu) although I didn't quite get the answer and the point might be a bit different.

I don't have the stock cooler for the 1155 processor, and have a 775 stock cooler that works just fine. I have a motherboard that seems to have the holes for both 775 and 1155.
[image]

What I want to ask, if I manage to stick correctly this heatsink, will it work fine or will it have some thermal problems? (because the coolers might be different)

edit: on a side note, I have seen that the 755 P4 3.0ghz TDP is bigger than my present CPU (84 W against 69W). I dunno if this means much though.

Comment: What was the TDP of the original processor it was for and what is the TDP of this one?

Comment: I was just adding that information to the question :P

Answer (score 1):

If it fits over the CPU and makes contact and mounts to your motherboard, you'll be fine. Since your current CPU has a lower TPU than the CPU that the cooler came with, it's more than adequate for cooling the newer processor.